# on click of Component ,member variable get reinitialised? any other approach to avoid it?

Tags: angular, observable

On addItem items get push into productList array, but On click of the cart tab, productList in cartcomponent get reinitialised(its emptying the productList array).how to avoid the reinitialising the array ?

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    public productList: any[] = [];
    constructor(private ShopDataService: ShopDataService) {
        this.ShopDataService.getValue()
            .subscribe(
                products => {
                    this.productList.push(products);
                    console.log("cart::" + this.productList);

                });

    }
}


export class ShopDataService {
    private products: BehaviorSubject < any[] > = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    constructor() {}
    public setValue(value): void {
        this.products.next(value);
    }

    public getValue(): Observable < any[] > {
        return this.products;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share some more code?

Comment: Getting problem on click of same active tab??

Comment: I am adding product in to cart from another component, and to view cart (list of product added into the cart) i have to click on cart tab

Comment: Cart tab contains it's own component?

Comment: yes @RajaMohamed

Comment: You can store current cart item list in shopdataservice and get it on load of the component right , single ton services  will hold ur data entire components

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
    export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
public productList: any[] = [];
constructor(private ShopDataService: ShopDataService) {
    this.productList = this.ShopDataService.oldList;
    this.ShopDataService.getValue()
        .subscribe(
            products => {
                this.productList.push(products);
                this.ShopDataService.oldList = this.productList;
                console.log("cart::" + this.productList);

            });

}}
 export class ShopDataService {
     public oldList : any[];
     private products: BehaviorSubject < any[] > = new BehaviorSubject([]);
     constructor() {}
     public setValue(value): void {
          this.products.next(value);
     }

     public getValue(): Observable < any[] > {
          return this.products;
     }
```

}

**Try this**

Comment: at this line, this.ShopDataService.oldList = this.productList; in the component, it resets the array again

Comment: Have you injected  ShopDataService in  root cofig or module  page..?

Comment: It should be configured only once in entire app

Comment: root config @raja mohamed

Comment: Then it's single ton service and it should hold values across components.

Comment: Could you change private private products: BehaviorSubject < any[] > = new BehaviorSubject([]);  to public?

Comment: Print console in service constructor and check it's printing Everytime ?, If prints Everytime it's service instance issue

Comment: whenever i add product ,  this.ShopDataService.oldList  is also updating, but again same issue, when i click on cart tab ProductList get update and it updates the  this.ShopDataService.oldList

Comment: Constructor executing every time in service?

Comment: no, constructor executes only once when component loads for the first time,   this.productList = this.ShopDataService.oldList;gives error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Can you create and share in plunker